# no overload for method 'Play' takes 0 arguments, more context

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im not really sure whats wrong, I'm pretty inexperienced with C#, and i posted this with everyone saying there isn't enough context, so Im posting the whole script. It isn't that long though, I just **need** this help!

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

[RequireComponent(typeof(AudioSource))]
public class MusicPlayer : MonoBehaviour {
public GUISkin skin;

public Song[] playlist;
public AudioClip mlgSong;
public AudioSource fastSource;

int currentSongID;
bool isPlaying;

[System.NonSerialized]
public bool fastMode = false;

string currentSongCredits;

//Song credits
float timer = 0;
float slidePosition;
float slidePositionMax = 20;

void Start() {
    slidePosition = slidePositionMax;
    ShuffleSongs();
    audio.clip = playlist[0].clip;
    currentSongID = 0;
    isPlaying = audio.isPlaying;
    if (!GameSettings.music) {
        fastSource.Stop();
    }
}
void Update() {

    if ((!audio.isPlaying || GameSettings.keybinds.GetKeyDown("nextsong")) && isPlaying) {
        if (currentSongID<playlist.Length-1) {

            currentSongID++;
        } else {
            currentSongID = 0;
        }
        audio.clip = playlist[currentSongID].clip;
        slidePosition = slidePositionMax;
        Play (); //The error is here...


    }
    if ((!audio.isPlaying || GameSettings.keybinds.GetKeyDown("lastsong")) && isPlaying) {
        if (currentSongID<playlist.Length+1) {

            currentSongID++;
        } else {
            currentSongID = playlist.Length;
        }
        audio.clip = playlist[currentSongID].clip;
        slidePosition = slidePositionMax;
        Play (); //The error is also here. 

    }
    //Timer
    if (timer > 0) {
        timer -= Time.deltaTime;
    }

    if (fastMode && fastSource.volume < 1) {
        fastSource.volume = Mathf.Min(1,fastSource.volume + Time.deltaTime * 0.25f);
        audio.volume = 0.5f - fastSource.volume/2;
    }
    if (!fastMode && fastSource.volume > 0) {
        fastSource.volume = Mathf.Max(0,fastSource.volume - Time.deltaTime * 0.5f);
        audio.volume = 0.5f - fastSource.volume/2;
    }
    if (timer > 0) {
        slidePosition = Mathf.Lerp(slidePosition,0,Time.deltaTime);
    } else {
        slidePosition = Mathf.Lerp(slidePosition,slidePositionMax,Time.deltaTime);
    }

}
public void Pause() {
    Play (playlist[currentSongID].name);
}
public void Play(string credits) {
    currentSongCredits = "Now playing: " + credits;
    if (FindObjectOfType<MlgMode>() != null) {//IS MLG MODE
        audio.clip = mlgSong;
        currentSongCredits = "Now playing: xXxSW3GST3PxXx";
        FindObjectOfType<MlgMode>().StartTheShit();//Start the wubs
    }
    isPlaying = true;
    if (!audio.mute) {
        timer = 8;
    }
    audio.Play();
}


void OnGUI() {
    if (slidePosition < slidePositionMax-0.1f) {
        GUI.skin = skin;
        GUIStyle style = new GUIStyle(GUI.skin.label);
        style.fontSize = 16;
        style.alignment = TextAnchor.MiddleRight;
        Rect rect = new Rect(0,Screen.height-30+slidePosition,Screen.width,30);

        //GUIX.ShadowLabel(rect,currentSongCredits,style,1);
        GUILayout.BeginArea(rect);
        GUILayout.FlexibleSpace (); //Push down
        GUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
        GUILayout.FlexibleSpace(); //Push to the right
            GUILayout.Label(currentSongCredits,GUI.skin.GetStyle("SoundCredits"),GUILayout.ExpandWidth(false));
        GUILayout.EndHorizontal();
        GUILayout.EndArea();
    }
}

void ShuffleSongs() {
    //Shuffle playlist using Fisher-Yates algorithm
    for (int i = playlist.Length;i > 1;i--) {
        int j = Random.Range(0,i);
        Song tmp = playlist[j];
        playlist[j] = playlist[i - 1];
        playlist[i - 1] = tmp;
    }
}

}

[System.Serializable]
public class Song {
public string name;
public AudioClip clip;
}
```

Comment: Are you working from a tutorial? There's a curious increase of questions recently with that exact error message, all about some ominous Play() method. EDIT: apparently you asked that question 3 times total the last 5 days.

Comment: Error message is self explanatory! You are trying to invoke `Play` method, without arguments but it expects one.

Comment: possible duplicate of [No overload for method 'Play' takes '0' arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27338870/no-overload-for-method-play-takes-0-arguments)

Comment: Duplicate question asked my `same user` :)

Answer (score 0):

Your `Play` method is declared like this:

```
public void Play(string credits)
```

but you are calling it like this:

```
Play();
```

You need to include a `string` as a parameter when you call it.

```
Play("White and Nerdy - Weird Al Yankovic");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `Play(string credits)` method is expecting a string called credits. Since you call `Play()` without putting a string there, it is giving you an error.

What it is looking for is an overloaded method, another form of Play() without the string and when it doesn't find that you receive that error.